# How to get player name from OwnerActorNr | PUN2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm making an online game and when a ball hit by a player hits another player, I want to get that player's name from OwnerActorNr.

```
photonView.OwnerActorNr
```

Is it possible to get player information from this number?

Comment: just access `photonView.NickName`

Comment: photonView.NickName gets only the name of the owner of the photonView. I mean, I want to get that player's name from another player's OwnerActorNr. Like PhotonView.GetName(int ActorNr).

Comment: when you access `photonView.OwnerActorNr` you get the actor number of the given photon view. so even if you sent it somewhere else to handle it, it will return the name of the given photon view. or if you have only the actor number without the photon view, you could find it in `PhotonNetwork.PlayerList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PhotonNetwork.Currentroom.GetPlayer(ActorNumber);`

It will return the `player`. You can use the `player` properties like `nickname`, etc..